# Algorithm for finding minimums in list for all possible subranges

Tags: algorithm

Say I have a list:

`L = [2,5,1,8,3,7,9,4,6,10]` 
or something similar

And I want to be able to create a two-dimensional list/array/etc that describes the minimums for all possible ranges (e.g. minimums[0][3] represents the smallest value when looking at elements 0 through 3).

For example:

```
Range(0 through 3) = minimum is 1
Range(5 through 5) = minimum is 7
Range(3 through 8) = minimum is 3
```

And so on, for all possible ranges. Is there a way to do this better than n^2 time?

Comment: I think this is a [range minimum query problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_Minimum_Query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a segment tree for it. And the query time will be O(logn).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it would be computationally impossible to impose that type of algorithm in less than n^2 time. This would be due to the fact that you are starting with a series of random lists. Even if you put items in one by one the finding of a minimum would be slightly lower(maybe). That however takes up time as well. The only way to possibly lower the time in is to order the lists, but then we must consider amortized time.

Comment: I suspect it could be done faster using lazy lists, or a function `f(x,y)` instead of an array access. Also, amortized cannot be trivially used, since one might use this function and check for only one range, which will still result in `O(n^2)`, even with amortized complexity.

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting http://projecteuler.net/problem=375 (which I assume you're not)
Then your question is likely to be an XY question:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341

The solution I propose (and i have no idea if it would be fast or not, or even accurate) is:

```
given your list L, create some more lists L1, L2, .. etc
now for a given i, define L1[i] = j
(where j is the minimum j>i such that L[j] < L[i]
```

Now I propose you can create L1 in O(N)
Now say you want min(range(a,b)), `answer = L[L1[..L1[a]]]` (I think? .. keep nesting until you get j > b and you have gone past b, then go back one)

Now to speed this up, have L2 be a similar datastructure to L1, but L2 skips two at a time.
L3 skips 4 at a time, L4 skips 8 a time.

Now you can use binary search on the different L datastructures.